# C# windows service multiple threads high CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, cpu-usage

I am working on windows service.
I am need to thread 380 methods in a program.
Here is my code.
threadChunkList is a list of 20 threads and there is an array of thread in the list.

like this.

```
List<Thread[]> threadChunkList = new List<Thread[]>();
```

When it comes to following loop to execute method, the CPU usage in the task manager goes to over 90%.

```
foreach (Thread[] mainthread in threadChunkList)
            {
                Thread OneFinalThread = null;

                OneFinalThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    foreach (Thread chunkthread in mainthread)
                    {                          
                        chunkthread.Start();                            
                    }
                    foreach (var thread in mainthread)
                    {
                        thread.Join();
                    }
                });
                OneFinalThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                OneFinalThread.Start();

                for (; ; )
                {
                    if (OneFinalThread.IsAlive)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone please let me know what is going wrong with above code. Also I dont know its proper way to manage thread or now. How can I use sleep method for thread to reduce CPU usage and how to remove previous thread from memory to clear memory?

Thank you

Comment: do a `OneFinalThread.Join();` instead of that for loop? And maybe don't use 380 threads?

Comment: sorry, which loop?

Comment: you have a for(;;) { if { } else{break;}}

Comment: what would you suggest over thread?

Comment: use TPL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx but in all cases make sure only a couple of threads/tasks do the work. Having more threads doesn't speed up things by magic.

Comment: Sounds like using TPL could be better option. Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: Only few threads. A number over 2xCPU cores (+/-) seems not give benefit.